# Incomming call UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm in the process of making a video conferencing app were a user can "call" a user to establish a connection via sockets.
At the moment the app displays a dialog with the options to accept or decline the call. 
I would like to replace that dialog with the native call UI, how can this be done? I read a little of ConnectionService, do I need to make my own UI?

[image: Incomming call UI]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing in call app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861910/replacing-in-call-app)

Comment: AFAIK android does not provide any Call-kit Pre-build UI . So you need to create this yourself ..

Comment: @ADM ah that's unfortunate, thanks for the reply. I'll be making my own then.